# How to package Web application separating web services and HTML/JS

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat, war

We're trying to split our web application which is currently packaged as a single WAR file. We'd like to package the web services (RESTful) part, which relies on Spring Boot, into a single WAR. Separately we would like to be able to deploy the front-end part, containing all the HTML/JS components.

We're using Tomcat 8 as the application container.

We already have separated the code and have generated the .WAR for the web services, which is okay. We're wondering how to do it for the HTML/JS part. How to package it, using Maven? How to deploy and start it with Tomcat? And then how to configure Tomcat so that both parts of the application share the same endpoint:

- localhost:8080:application/ for the HTML/JS part
- localhost:8080:application/rest/ for the web services running under SpringBoot.

All we have for now is a manual copy of the HTML/JS files into the webapps folder of tomcat, but this is not satisfying for easy deployment. Plus we didn't manage to configure the endpoint in Tomcat.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What front-end framework are you using?

Comment: We're using AngularJS. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways and tools to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

I'm going to suggest a way to do it with a few tools I've picked up in a similar project. While this answer may seem opinion oriented, it may give you a few ideas to start with and make your own choices.

If any of the steps described below needs more detail, let me know and I'll update them.

**How to package it, using Maven?**

The first thing you'll need to do is split your project into at least two modules :

- a war module with your REST services
- a client module with the static files.

To build the client module, you could use [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/). It will help you manage simple tasks on your static JS/HTML/CSS files. 
You can launch gulp tasks with the `frontend-maven-plugin` by `com.github.eirslett` :

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
   <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>install node and npm</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>v6.9.1</nodeVersion>
            <npmVersion>3.10.9</npmVersion>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>npm install</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>npm</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <arguments>install</arguments>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>npm rebuild node-sass</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>npm</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <arguments>rebuild node-sass</arguments>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>gulp build</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>gulp</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <arguments>build --no-notification</arguments>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>gulp test</id>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>gulp</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <arguments>test - - no-notification</arguments>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

In this example, the plugin launches the required steps :

- npm install -> needed for gulp
- gulp build -> your client side module build
- gulp test -> your client side unit tests

Then you'll need a gulpfile at the root of your module.

The least thing gulp needs to do now, is give the rest services backend's URL to your clent application. You're using angular, so I advise you to use `gulp-ng-constant` to modifiy angular constants on the fly during the build phase :

```
const ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant');

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('ngconstant:prod', gulp.parallel('other', 'webpack:dist')));

    gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
      return ngConstant({
          name: 'yourApp',
          constants: {
              BASE_URL : 'http://www.exemple.com:8080'
          },
          template: conf.constantTemplate,
          stream: true
      })
      .pipe(rename('app.constants.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.app + 'app/'));
    });
```

In the above gulpfile, [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) is used to do the actual build.

**How to deploy and start it with Tomcat?**

> - localhost:8080:application/ for the HTML/JS part
> - localhost:8080:application/rest/ for the web services running under
>     SpringBoot.

I wouldn't do it this way. It seems complicated to have your webapp and client application on the same context root in Tomcat.

Instead, I advise you to deploy your static files to a different context root or to a different Http Server, like an Apache http server. Technically, your client application doesn't need an application server. And deploying it to a regular, lighter and faster http server like Apache would allow it to still be up when you're restarting your Tomcat server.

Then you'll end up with :

- http://www.exemple.com/ for your client application
- http://www.exemple.com:8080/services/ for your services webapp

Now your client application is on a different host than your services webapp. And it will cause Cross-origin errors. So you're going to have to configure [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to allow your client application to send requests to your services webapp.

Another solution could be to set your Apache as a proxy for your tomcat. You could use define a VirtualHost that would forward all requests from port 8080 to the tomcat server.